# How to download all images one by one and show progress status

Tags: android, android-asynctask, client-server, android-async-http

I want to download all the images I have on server in the array string of Url one by one so that I may do not have to download a zip file of images from the server and to unzip after downloading it.

So I thought to download the images one by one and to show the download status in the progress bar.  But I am extremely failed in it. An Idea came into my mind to make the string array of the Url and to use the For loop to download but it is downloading the last image of the String array and decline or pass all other images in the array . I think I have got the idea that what is going on but I have know Idea what would be the solution then.

**What I have done So far**

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        try {
            //set the download URL, a url that points to a file on the internet
            //this is the file to be downloaded
            String [] imageUrl = {"http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/india.png","http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/pakistan.png"
                    ,"http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/china.png","http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/unitedstates.png"};
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            for(int i=0;i<imageUrl.length;i++){
                 url = new URL(imageUrl[i]);

                //create the new connection
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                //set up some things on the connection
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                //and connect!
                urlConnection.connect();

            }
            File storagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "Test");
            storagePath.mkdirs();
            String finalName = Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis());
            File myImage = new File(storagePath, finalName + ".png");


            //this will be used to write the downloaded data into the file we created
            FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(myImage);

            //this will be used in reading the data from the internet
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            //this is the total size of the file
            int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
            //variable to store total downloaded bytes
            int downloadedSize = 0;

            //create a buffer...
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bufferLength = 0; //used to store a temporary size of the buffer

            //now, read through the input buffer and write the contents to the file
            while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                //add the data in the buffer to the file in the file output stream (the file on the sd card
                fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                //add up the size so we know how much is downloaded
                downloadedSize += bufferLength;
                //this is where you would do something to report the prgress, like this maybe
               // updateProgress(downloadedSize, totalSize);

            }
            //close the output stream when done
            fileOutput.close();

            //catch some possible errors...
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // see http://androidsnippets.com/download-an-http-file-to-sdcard-with-progress-notification
        return null;
    }
```

** What I want :**

> 1. Download all the images one by one.
> 2. After downloading one Image it should get save in the device and update the progress status.

Please show me some source code rather then giving me just Idea how to do it. And little source code and complete work around on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `saving image code` should be taken **inside  `for`  loop**. as this code is outside of `for` loop only your last image is getting saved as at the end of for loop last url is used.

Comment: We do not see a progress bar in your code. So how could it be updated then?